# How to find the resultant vector of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, vector

Consider a matrix(`m`) as

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

I define the vectors as

[image]

Clearly, there are `8` vectors and all pointing towards `5`. The angle between any two consecutive vectors is `2 Pi/8 = Pi/4`. The magnitude of each vector is defined as the difference between the central value (`5` in this case) and the value corresponding to the other element.

Therefore,

vector 1 has a magnitude of `|(5-1)|=4` and direction `7 Pi/4`,

vector 2 has a magnitude of `|(5-2)|=3` and direction `3Pi/2`,

vector 3 has a magnitude of `|(5-3)|=2` and direction `5Pi/4`,

vector 4 has a magnitude of `|(5-6)|=1` and direction `Pi`,

vector 5 has a magnitude of `|(5-9)|=4` and direction `3Pi/4`,

vector 6 has a magnitude of `|(5-8)|=3` and direction `Pi/2`,

vector 7 has a magnitude of `|(5-7)|=2` and direction `Pi/4`,

vector 8 has a magnitude of `|(5-4)|=1` and direction `0`,

Under the given construction how can I efficiently calculate the resultant vector?

[I want a generalized solution for this so that it can be applied for any length of `m`. ]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean be "generalized solution". Please give additional details. I am in particular puzzled about how to handle, say, a 6 x  6 matrix, which has not central element.

Comment: @m_goldberg You are right. The matrix should always be a squared matrix with an odd length.

Answer (score 0):

I leave it up to you (or someone else) to implement a version of `ArcTan` that satisfies your particular requirements for the angle, but here's what a solution can look like:

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
c = 1 + (Dimensions[m] - 1)/2;
weights = Abs[m - Extract[m, c]];
(vectors = MapIndexed[{#, ArcTan @@ (#2 - #)} &, weights, {2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Total@Flatten[vectors, 1]
```

> `{20, -((9 \[Pi])/4) + ArcTan[1/2] + ArcTan[2]}`