# How to change the kernel size in a custom image filter?

Tags: image-processing

consider a custom image filter as

```
myfilter := {-1, 1} #[[1, 1]] + {0, 1} #[[1, 2]] + {1, 1} #[[1, 3]] +
   {-1, 0} #[[2, 1]] + {0, 0} #[[2, 2]] + {1, 0} #[[2, 3]] +
   {-1, -1} #[[3, 1]] + {0, -1} #[[3, 2]] + {1, -1} #[[3, 3]] &
```

I want to apply this to the following image (`img`)

[image]

The syntax for custom image filter is:

```
ImageFilter[myfilter, img, r]
```

The above filter currently works for `r=3`. How can I generalize this to work for any value of `r`?

**Edit 1**

Given the size of the kernel `m` I can generate the following `Grid` of relative positions.

```
Manipulate[Grid[n = 2 m + 1;
  Table[{j - m - 1, m - i + 1}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]], {m, 1, 5, 1}]
```

But I don't understand how to fit this into the filter to get the desired result.

**Edit 2:**

Based on the suggestions given in the comments I have modified my filters in the following way:

```
 vectorAbs := 
 Norm[{-1, 1} #[[1, 1]] + {0, 1} #[[1, 2]] + {1, 1} #[[1, 3]] +
    {-1, 0} #[[2, 1]] + {0, 0} #[[2, 2]] + {1, 0} #[[2, 3]] +
    {-1, -1} #[[3, 1]] + {0, -1} #[[3, 2]] + {1, -1} #[[3, 3]]] &

vectorArg := 
 ArcTan[{-1, 1} #[[1, 1]] + {0, 1} #[[1, 2]] + {1, 1} #[[1, 3]] +
    {-1, 0} #[[2, 1]] + {0, 0} #[[2, 2]] + {1, 0} #[[2, 3]] +
    {-1, -1} #[[3, 1]] + {0, -1} #[[3, 2]] + {1, -1} #[[3, 3]]] &
```

Now, I need to apply the filters on each channel as follows:

```
channels = ColorSeparate[img];
ColorCombine[
 Table[ImageFilter[vectorAbs, channels[[i]], 1], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

This gives me

[image]

If I compare this result with the results using `RidgeFilter`, I get

[image]

I cannot thin the edges like this although it extracts a lot more feature boundaries.

If I use the `vectorArg` function, I get the two components like this

```
t = Table[
   ColorSeparate@ImageFilter[vectorArg, channels[[i]], 1], {i, 1, 3}];
{ColorCombine[Transpose[t][[1]]], ColorCombine[Transpose[t][[2]]]}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This filter doesn't work. It gives a pair of numbers instead of a single number.  If you can generate the coefficients, then you can use `Total`. Your filter code can always detect the kernel size: it can see how big a block is passed to it.

Comment: Other minor things to note: 1. you don't need `:=` here, you can use `=`.  2. this specific type of filter is better implemented using `ImageConvolve`. But I assumed your question was general and meant to apply to any filter.

Comment: @Szabolcs The filter is supposed to give me the vector sum of all the components. That's why there is a pair of numbers. However, I am sorry, I still don't get your point. Can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by vector sum.  A pixel value should be a number (for each image channel). Your function returns a pair of numbers. That's not valid for an image, and thus the example you showed fails with an error.

Comment: Other than this, what you are computing is basically a convolution. Why don't you use `ImageConvolve`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Please follow this link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165861/how-to-find-the-resultant-vector-of-a-matrix